# Auto update externals revision

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I am currently using externals to substitute symlinks in my repo, because I have working copies on Windows and Linux. The reason for this is that I want my code to build on both.

So I currently use externals which includes only folders of the repo itself. Now I must update the externals myself everytime I make a commit to a folder beeing referenced by an external.

My question is whether there is an automated tool from svn or if I have to automate this myself with a post-commit-hook?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve: What do you mean by having working copies on Windows and Linux? How is this related to o your externals? Could you maybe do some sort of (ascii) graphic to illustrate your structure?

Comment: i cannot version the symlinks because windows and linux have different symlinks-formats

Comment: and I must test the compilation on both because it is platform dependent c++ code